# Using pytest-django and setup takes 7 or 8 minutes?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am setting up pytest testing for our Django site and it is taking seven or eight (7 or 8) minutes to finish running a single test in which less than a hundred objects are created. This feels like its going to be a massive impediment to developing tests if I can only try five things an hour (given that I will be sure to waste several of those tries on stupid mistakes like typos in filepaths.)

platform win32 -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
Django 3.1.5

Our site uses django-simple-history (which creates a history counterpart of every table) and django-taggit, and has maybe 25 different apps, of which a couple provide widely reused models (if that matters).  Could be 100 or more models all up.  My laptop has 8Gb RAM, and an older i7 CPU.

I have set the reusedb option in pytest.ini, but there is no perceptible change.  Is this a fixable problem?

This is the code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_proj_creation():
    for i in range(5):
        groupname = "G" + str(i)
        group = Group.objects.create(name=groupname)
        username = "U" + str(i)
        user = User.objects.create(username=username)
        user.set_password(username)
        user.groups.set(Group.objects.all())
        proj_name = "P" + str(i)
        project = Project.objects.create(project_name=proj_name)
        project.target_groups.add(group)
        assert user.groups.count() == i+1
```

When run:

```
========================================================================================================= test session starts =========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
django: settings: mysite6.settings_components.development (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\Andrew\AzureKEN\KEN%20development, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.1.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

tests\pytest_site.py
```

And this is where the long pause happens.

Then:

```
========================================================================================================== warnings summary ===========================================================================================================
tests/pytest_site.py::test_proj_creation
  c:\users\andrew\djdev\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1367: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField HistoricalBRVM.last_modified received a naive datetime (1901-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
    warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
============================================================================================== 1 passed, 1 warning in 695.40s (0:11:35) ===============================================================================================
```

Comment: 7-8 minutes is abnormally slow. Have you managed to identify what is actually slowing down your tests? Is it the startup/initialisation or the actual running of the tests? Without knowing exactly what your app and tests look like it's almost impossible to give an answer, do you have an example of a slow running test or fixture?

Comment: I'll update - this was the case with a 'hello world'-level test.

Comment: Not clear from your code what would cause the slowness. Is there a long wait before the tests start running? How long does the app take to start when you run it?

Comment: The long pause is far longer than for example, the time to start the development server in Django (10 seconds say). I am checking OpenHardwareMonitor and CPU temps are close to the 75 deg max, but the reported speeds are still 2000MHz.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test line by line to find out which line(s) are slowest? Do you have a crazy amount of groups causing `user.groups.set` to be slow or do you have some signals running for your models?

Comment: I am leaning toward most of the time going into the set up of the django test database. The pytest.mark.django_db means that a database is created in memory and all the migrations are run on it. I am checking how long applying migrations takes and it turns out to be a lot - similar intervals. The 'reuse-db' option should enable this to happen only once.

Comment: Please put the code in pytest_site.py here

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question - the issue here is that

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
```

invokes creation of a blank sqlite database with all the tables created, which is a lot of work. This is  configured by running through all the django migrations scripts, and that process requires many minutes.  I can reduce this a bit by using the migration "squash" commands to reduce redundancy. The --reuse-db option doesn't seem to work (?) but in any case, we would normally expect to have database changes that would prevent reuse of an existing database.